# Hiding a Master View Controller when Selection is Made with Xcode 4.3.2 Storyboards

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to hide the master view controller when a cell is selected only when the iPad is in portrait view. So the user will click the cell and then the master view controller will go away (like in Mail). Where and how would I do this?

[image]

This project is open source: https://github.com/kirkouimet/enzyme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you configure your detail view controller, you need to dismiss the popover controller.

```
if (self.popoverController) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

If your detail view controller doesn't already have a property to hold the `UIPopoverController`, you can capture it by implementing these delegate methods for `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)iSplitViewController
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)iBarButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)iPopoverController {

    self.popoverController = iPopoverController;
}


- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)iSplitViewController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)iBarButtonItem {

    self.popoverController = nil;
}
```

Comment: This is not working first time as willHideViewController is not called till your device's orientation is changed, and ultimately self.popoverController is remained unassigned. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Get Register for notification on you detail view.

1)On your detail view get register for notification.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad

 {

        //for showing loginview
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
        selector:@selector(dismissPop) name:@"MASTERROWSELECTED" object:nil];

  }
```

2)On your master view on didSelectRowAtIndexPath do this;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

         //do normal things you usually do

        //post notification that row is selected and you need to dismiss popover.

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MASTERROWSELECTED" 
         object:nil];

  }
```

3) write this method on your detail view.

```
- (void)dismissPop
{

      if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
      {

             //self.popover is your reference to master view pop 
             if([self.popover isPopoverVisible])
             {
                 [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
             }
      }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by using a custom SplitViewController such as Matt Gemmell's [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/).  In particular, this implementation adds a `toggleMasterView:` method to the controller, which you could call from within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: How hard is it for me to switch over to MGSplitViewController at this point? Can you outline basic instructions for me? Do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: You shouldn't need to start from scratch.  All the API/delegate methods from the stock UISplitViewController are the same, so you should be able to just switch out the stock controller for the new one.  The only caveat I see on the project page is that it might not show up quite the same in IB (storyboard editor), but if you instantiate an instance of the controller and set the master VC and detail VC outlets you should be fine.  (Disclaimer: I have not used this myself, so I'd be interested to hear if this is as easy as I think it would be.)

Comment: The only issue with doing this is that `MGSplitViewController` is **not** a descendant of `UISplitViewController`, so you couldn't use the split-view controller layout and interactions in Storyboards. You'd have to manage all of that programmatically.